# Load .html into div by using a search bar

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm primarily wondering if this is even possible without PHP, and perhaps some guidance if it is. I have the feeling I'm overthinking the process.

Currently I'm loading specific .html's into a div with ease by button clicks. However, I have been trying to load an .html into a div by using a search bar (as the title explicitly states).

For instance, I search for "Apple" and expect "Apple.html" to load into the div. I understand that javascript cannot/shouldn't search local files without the aid of PHP, but can it not 'assume' that the file is there and load it? According to my logic it wouldn't be much different than a button click.

Comment: Please share your code to debug easily

Comment: does "local" in your description mean "on your local hard drive" or "in the same directory on a server". Without a code (even if it's not working) it's really hard to help you- as you seam to be new here I guess it's a cross-origin-policy issue

Comment: I meant "local" as in my local hard drive. I apologize for the confusion as I tried so hard to be specific. 

As for my code, I had something similar as below, but lacked the correct implementation of the " $("#search").val() ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [jquery](https://jquery.com/)
your all files should be at same place where actual page exist otherwise you have to specify path also.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>html</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="search" id="search">
    <input type="button" id="button" name="">

    <div>

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#button").on('click', function(e){
        $('div').load($("#search").val() + ".html");
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should work perfectly. I'm guessing I can't find out of this works on a local drive (non server)?  Either way, thank you for the help!